# Android Moto G - sleep causes destroy message

Tags: android, motorola-droid

Im currently fixing bugs when my app is not the main active app.  Most devices i get a PAUSE message, LOST messages etc.  These are all as I expect.  The thing i dont get is on the Moto G device i always get a destroy message when returning to the app menus etc, or the device is put to sleep.

Is there any reason for this?  I am fixing it up, but it seems harsh to have to destroy the app just because you get a phone call or sleep the device, its not like im loading up another complex game or anything

Answer (score 0):

The Moto G appears to have rather aggressive memory management. Android has a low memory killer, which determines which processes to kill depending on device configurations.

While the Moto G does have 1GB of RAM, the minfree settings applied by Motorola seem to kill apps on background.

There are instructions on the web as to how to address this as a user, but as a developer, it is likely best to save your state when you are backgrounded in onPause().

http://m.androidcentral.com/fine-tuning-minfree-settings-improving-androids-multi-tasking

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle